# How to find field with date range?

Tags: sql, vb.net

So I'm trying to select record with a specific date range ex. 5/21/2019 - 5/30/2019 and put the records into a datagridview.

I'm using Ms. Access and I don't know many things about SQL.

```
DA = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table where date >= " & DateValue(FirstDate) & " AND date <= " & DateValue(SecondDate) & "", conn)  
DS = New DataSet
DS.Clear()
DA.Fill(DS, "table")
DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables("table")
```

It doesn't give me an error message, but the datagridview doesn't show anything. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, the date delimiter is a hash (#).

So have to change your query to:

```
"SELECT * FROM table where date >= #" & DateValue(FirstDate) & "# AND date <= #" & DateValue(SecondDate) & "#"
```

Or you use the between operator:

```
"Select * FROM table WHERE [Date] Between #" & DateValue(FirstDate) & "# and #" & DateValue(SecondDate) & "#";
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to handle this is to simply use parameters which is commonly recommended by many programmers.

```
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table where date >= @StartDate AND date <= @EndeDate ", conn)
    'If you show how you declare and set FirstDate and SecondDate we can drop the DateValue function'
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = DateValue(FirstDate)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndeDate", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = DateValue(SecondDate)
    ds = New DataSet
    DS.Clear()
    DA.Fill(DS, "table")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables("table")
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT ID
FROMTestInfo
WHERE CapturedDate BETWEEN ‘2012-03-27’ AND ‘2012-03-28 ’

Comment: you are using wrong way in SQL query. please try this way.

Comment: go through the link for more information

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/355235/How-to-search-between-two-dates-and-get-all-record